# Java java server pages and netbeans

Tags: java, jsp

I have developed a `.jsp` website using NetBeans. It is working perfectly well when I run it from NetBeans but when I clean and build the project and copy the `.war` file from the dist folder and copy in the webapps folder of the TomCat 5.0 that is installed alongwith no `.jsp` file is being executed.

The error shows:

```
exception

    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:97)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:346)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:414)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:472)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:451)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:439)
        org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:511)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:295)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:292)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:236)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)

root cause

Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK
    org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.CompilerAdapterFactory.getCompiler(CompilerAdapterFactory.java:106)
        org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:935)
        org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:764)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:382)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:472)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:451)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:439)
        org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:511)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:295)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:292)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:236)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
```

Sometimes while cleaning and building the project an error occurs in NetBeans that MySQL `driver.jar` i.e. included library cannot be deleted.

Comment: Upgrade your Tomcat, it is extremely old!

Answer (score 1):

tomcat uses environment variable `JAVA_HOME`, set it to point to your `jdk`